# jmeter regarding performance and load testing

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

Let me describe the issue which i have been facing.

i want to do performance and load testing on our internal website. which has login and other functionalities.

the issue i am facing that when i hit 12 or any number of request using http sampler then i am getting same response from all the 12 request. But actual scenario is that webpage displays different data for different page.

I checked using firebug and everything is working fine over there using correct response from request but when i use jmeter i am using same response from every request.

Please let me know if anybody had faced same kind of issue of is there anything i am doing wrong in configuring script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test-plan to the root (Test Plan) node or to the Thread Group node.
   As per [jmeter documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html):

   > The last element is a HTTP Cookie Manager. A Cookie Manager should be
   >   added to all web tests - otherwise JMeter will ignore cookies. By
   >   adding it at the Thread Group level, we ensure that all HTTP requests
   >   will share the same cookies.
2. Ensure that parameters values that are dynamic are not hard-coded (after recording jmeter scripts, for example): no hard-coded `JSessionID` values in your HTTP requests, e.g..
3. Ensure you don't miss any necessary params in your HTTP requests.
4. **JMeter does not process Javascript or applets embedded in HTML pages.**
   Your problem may be caused by this feature.
   As per [jmeter documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterFAQ#Does_JMeter_process_dynamic_pages_.28e.g._Javascript_and_applets.29):

   > JMeter does not process Javascript or applets embedded in HTML pages.
   >
   > JMeter can download the relevant resources (some embedded resources
   >   are downloaded automatically if the correct options are set), but it
   >   does not process the HTML and execute any Javascript functions.
   >
   > If the page uses Javascript to build up a URL or submit a form, you
   >   can use the Proxy Recording facility to create the necessary sampler.
   >   If this is not possible, then manual inspection of the code may be
   >   needed to determine what the Javascript is doing.

I would also recommend your to look first into Jmeter reference before further scripting activities - this may prevent from some faults and frustration.

At least these:

- [Building a Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-test-plan.html)
- [Elements of a Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html)
- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Alies thanks for your quick reply.Points 1 to 3 i am sure there is not mistake from my side as i am recording script using bad boy tool and exporting script to jmeter so it configures automatically everything. But point 4 i am still researching it might look like logical.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest - Use Jmeter's Regular Expressions. You may be able to resolve this issue with RegEx. Post using regex, use 'View Results Tree' listener to check if you are getting apt response for each of your threads.

You can also analyze your results using [Blazemeter's listener](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-load-test-results-using-new-blazemeter-listener) that gives you more insights into your test.